# Is the a way to pass preprocessor macro to `eosiocpp` for specific types of compilation

Tags: compilation, debugging

I would like to develop my contracts in a way where I can pass a compile time flag to enable/disable debugging code so that the debugging functionality would not be compiled into the "production" version of the contract. eg.

```
#if DEBUG
  void cleartables() {
    // clear all table code here
  }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your variables in the environment variable `EOSIOCPP_CFLAGS`. If you are curious, just open the *eosiocpp* file (it's a bash script, a wrapper over clang) to see how the variable is used.

Comment: Thanks. It's taken me a while to get around to it but that helped a lot. Ive been able to pass macros into eosio-cpp with the newer tools and get exactly what I need done.

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass the values when you compile the contract e.g. `eosio-cpp -D=DEBUG ...`